# Solve for $y''+2y'+y = \frac{e^{-t}}{t^{2}}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need some help in finding the solution to this second-order non-homogeneous DE.

I know how to find the solution of the reduced equation $$y''+2y'+y=0.$$

The characteristic equation $r^{2}+2r+1=0$ yields real and repeated roots $r=-1$. So the complementary solution, $$y_{c}= c_{1}e^{-t} + c_{2}te^{-t}$$.

Now what I am struggling with is making educated guesses about coming up with a particular solution. So any suggestions on that would be helpful.

**EDIT1:** I haven't learned about the method of variation of parameters yet and wanted to do this with the method of undetermined coefficients. Please feel free to post the solution by using any of the techniques so I can learn from it.

**EDIT2:** Our fundamental pair of solutions for the corresponding homogeneous is $y_{1}=e^{-t}$, and $y_{2}=t e^{-t}$.

We know that our particular solution will be of the form, $y_{p} = u_{1} y_{1} + u_{2} y_{2}$.

The determinant of the Wronskian, $W = e^{-2t}$, with $W_{1} = -t^{-1} e^{-2t}$, and $W_{2} = t^{-1} e^{-2t}$.

So $u'_{1} = \frac{W_{1}}{W} = -\frac{1}{t}$, and $u'_{2} = \frac{W_{2}}{W} = \frac{1}{t}$.

So $u_{1} = -\int \frac{1}{t} dt = -ln|t|$, and $u_{2} = \int \frac{1}{t} dt = ln|t|$.

Hence, $y_{p} = -ln|t| e^{-t} + ln|t|te^{-t}$.

So our general solution, $$y = y_{c} + y_{p} = e^{-t}(c_{1}+c_{2}t-ln|t|+ln|t|t).$$

Does it look okay?

Comment: Generally you only do particular solutions if it's a polynomial times a sine/cosine times an exponential, not a rational function.  I'd use variation of paramaters

Comment: @Alan I haven't learned that technique yet. Is it the method of undetermined coeffecients?

Comment: What techniques have you learnt?

Comment: @Mattos Separation of variables technique and learned method of undetermined coefficients today. Seeing youtube videos on change of var technique. Is it possible to solve this problem by the method of undetermined coefficients technique?

Comment: Have you been asked to use undetermined coefficients method?

Comment: @science Not really, but that's where we are right now.

Comment: This can be solved by variation of parameters method!

Comment: @user36829 If you want, I'll post a solution using variation of parameters.

Comment: @Mattos Thanks. I am actually on my way to learning it and doing some examples.

Comment: @user36829 Wait, you want me to post the solution or you don't want me to post the solution?

Comment: @Mattos Yes, you can post the solution. I am also doing it right now with the Wronskian, so we both can check.

Comment: @Mattos I have made an edit.

Comment: Differentiating your answer gives $y'' + 2y' + y = \frac{e^{-t}}{t^{2}} - \frac{e^{-t}}{t}$ so you are off by the $\frac{e^{-t}}{t}$ term. Give it another go.

Comment: @Mattos Argh! You can post your solution and I'll accept it hehe.

Comment: The solution is given by $y = e^{-t}(C_1 + C_2t - \ln \vert t \vert)$.. Keep trying, you've done well so far, working through is the best way to learn. If you are still having trouble with it in an hour, post a comment to me and I'll write up the solution.

Comment: @Mattos Well, I tried, but couldn't really find my mistake.

Comment: @user36829 Sure, I'll do it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already got

$$y_h = c_1e^{-t} + c_2te^{-t}$$

with

$$y_1 = e^{-t} \ \ \ \ \ y_2 = te^{-t}$$

Taking the Wronskian, you also found

$$W = e^{-2t}$$

The particular solution is given by the formula

$$y_p = -y_1 \int \frac{y_2 g(t)}{W} dt + y_2 \int \frac{y_1 g(t)}{W} dt$$

where

$$g(t) = \frac{e^{-t}}{t^{2}} = t^{-2}e^{-t}$$

Hence

$$\begin{align}
y_p &= -e^{-t} \int \frac{te^{-t} \cdot t^{-2}e^{-t}}{e^{-2t}} dt + te^{-t} \int \frac{e^{-t} \cdot t^{-2}{e^{-t}}}{e^{-2t}} dt \\
&= -e^{-t} \int \frac{1}{t} dt + te^{-t} \int \frac{1}{t^{2}} dt \\
&= -e^{-t} \ln(t) - \frac{te^{-t}}{t} \\
&= -e^{-t}(\ln(t) + 1) \\
\end{align}$$

Therefore,

$$\begin{align}
y &= y_h + y_p \\
&= e^{-t}(c_1 + c_2 t - \ln(t) - 1) \\
\end{align}$$

You can check by differentiation that this satisfies the ODE.

Comment: $-1\cdot e^{-t}$ is an unnecessary part of the solution since it solves the homogeneous equation. I.e. the $-$ can be 'absorbed' into the $c_1$ coefficient.

Comment: @jdods Yeah and?

Answer (score 1):

In this case of only one characteristic value, also a change of function can help. Substitute, according to the homogeneous solution, $y(t)=e^{-t}u(t)$ to get for $u$
$$
u''(t)=t^{-2}\implies u'(t)=-t^{-1}+C\implies u(t)=-\ln|t|+Ct+D
$$
and thus
$$
y(t)=e^{-t}(-\ln|t|+Ct+D)
$$

Answer (score 0):

I'll use the formula I developed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1158877/a-different-variation-of-parameters-technique)
$$Y_p=y_h\int \left\{y_h^{-2} W_0 \left(\int y_h W_0^{-1} g \ dt\right)\right\} \ dt$$
where the Wronskian (up to a constant multiple) is 
$$W_{0}=\exp\left(-{\int p \ dt}\right)$$
and a solution to the homogeneous equation is $y_h=e^{-t}$ (we can use either).

So we first integrate 
$$W_{0}=\exp\left(-{\int 2 \ dt}\right)=e^{-2t}$$
and then we'll find the particular solution by
$$
\begin{aligned}
Y_p&=e^{-t}\int \left\{e^{2t} e^{-2t} \left(\int e^{-t} e^{2t} \frac{e^{-t}}{t^2} \ dt\right)\right\} \ dt \\
&=e^{-t}\int \left(\int \frac{1}{t^2} \ dt\right) \ dt \\
&=e^{-t}\int \left(-\frac{1}{t}\right) \ dt \\
&=-e^{-t}\ln t.
\end{aligned}
$$

This is a nice formula because you only need one solution to the homogeneous equation.