# Variation of parameters formula with complex imaginary roots

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am needing to use the Variation of parameters formula to solve a second order non-homogeneous equation. I have used this before however i now have an equation with complex imaginary roots

My second order differential equation is y'' + 2y' + 2y = exp(-t)sin(t)

so i'm working with the roots to the characteristic equation λ^2 + 2λ + 2 = 0

Do i just use the formula normally or is there a different method for complex imaginary roots?

Comment: Just use the quadratic formula as normal.

Comment: But how would I go about integrating something with imaginary i in it?

Comment: Ok, it sounds like there's some confusion so edit your post to include the entire question and we'll go through it.

Comment: Also, [here's](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1134255/solve-for-y2yy-frace-tt2/1134495#1134495) a previous question I solved using the variation of parameters (although it doesn't have complex solutions which is where I think you're having trouble). You might like to have a look through it.

Comment: thanks Mattos but yes it is purely the complex imaginary solutions which are stumping me at the moment

Comment: Don't worry about them being complex, you can always use Eulers formula to turn them into $\sin$ and $\cos$. Your $\lambda_{1,2} = -1 \pm i$, hence your two solutions to the homogeneous equation are $y_1 = e^{(-1 + i)t}$ and $y _ 2 = e^{(-1 - i)t}$. Now you need to calculate your Wronskian and find the particular solution.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever there's an $i$, turn it into sines and cosines. In your characteristic equation, the roots are $\lambda = -1 \pm i$, so the general solution is

$$ y_h = C_1 e^{(-1 + i) t} + C_2 e^{(-1 - i) t}$$ $$ = C_1e^{-t}e^{it} + C_2 e^{-t} e^{-it}$$ $$ = C_1e^{-t}(\cos t + i\sin t) + C_2e^{-t}(\cos t - i\sin t) $$ $$ = (C_1 + C_2)\,e^{-t}\cos t + i(C_1 - C_2)\,e^{-t}\sin t $$ $$ = A_1 e^{-t}\cos t + A_2 e^{-t}\sin t  $$

Comment: Thanks, from your response I realize that we can use A2 to absorb the imaginary number I.